# Google cloud GPU machines reboot abruptly

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, cloud, gcloud

When training a model on the GPU machine, it get interrupted due to some system patch process. Since Google cloud GPU machines do not have an option of live migration, it is painful task to restart the training every time this happens. Google has clearly mentioned that there is no way around this but to restart the machines in this [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#host-maintenance).
Is there a clever way to detect if the machine is rebooted and resume the training automatically.
Sometimes it also happens that due to some kernel update, the CUDA drivers stop working and GPU is not visible and CUDA drivers need a re-installation. So writing a startup script to resume the training is also not a bulletproof solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. If you use tensorflow, you can use it's checkpointing feature to save your progress and pick up where you left off.

One great example of this is provided here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/gce/survival-training/README-tf-estimator.md